# C# Linq: Sequence Contains no elements, while binding large number of records to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I am trying below query to bind data in Gridview using ASP.NET C# and Linq. My database table has around **55K records**. I have gridview placed in user control.

```
private void DisplayData()
{
    Search s = new Search();
    search.GetAllSearchRequests(int.MaxValue);

    Grid.Bind(search.Results);
}

public void GetAllSearchRequests(int count)
{
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            var db = (from s in db.SomeTable
                      orderby s.ID descending
                      select s).Take(count);

            var dbList = db.ToList();
        }
}
```

I am facing issue binding this much records. Application is running for 4-5 minutes and then suddenly it shows below error message:

**"Sequence contains no elements."**

I have tried most possible solutions I found so far on Stackoverflow, but couldn't get through.

I appreciate community's advise.

Also, I am getting access to dbList variable by passing to below method to convert it to my user defined class list.

```
    private void convertToList(List<PLANVORGANG> dbRequests)
    {

        foreach (var dbRequest in dbRequests)
        {
            ServiceRequest svcRequest = new ServiceRequest();
            ServiceRequestMapper.MapRequestFromDBObject(dbRequest, svcRequest);
            Results.Add(svcRequest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you try binding it by returning the data into a `DataTable` then also what does Grid.Bind look like.. is this a function your wrote. ? perhaps you can filter down the GetAllSearchRequest by using a `WHERE` clause also `search.GetAllSearchRequests(int.MaxValue);` this looks a bit odd you would have  to know how many records you want to search on initially ..then allow the user to have some filter functionality so that they can get more specific records for example Select on the TOP 100 rows meaning you would need to use the `Take` on a smaller count.. have you tried returning 100

Comment: also `how are you gaining access to `var dbList = db.ToList();` dbList in this code.. it's out of scope once you leave the method.. voided methods don't return values you need to show all relevant code / classes etc.. that you have reference to in the code that you posted..

Comment: @MethodMan, I am applying WHERE clause as search criteria once all records are loaded and bound with gridview. Perhaps I will try your datatable concept. Yes, I tried returning 45,000 records. But afterwards as I increase the record count, let's say 50,000, it crashes.

Comment: Sounds like it hits a timeout. Try set the commandtimeout to a vey high number e.g. this.context.Database.CommandTimeout = 99999999;

Comment: @MethodMan, I tried applying your suggestion using Datatable but couldn't see any difference. Then I passed definite number of record count to retrieve and then configured search parameters to retrieve records.